# i'm getting this error while installing msqlclient. even i installed visual c++ but the same issue is coming

Tags: python, windows

i'm getting this error while installing mysql client. even i installed visual c++ but the same issue is coming.

i have searched for this type of error but i did not found it.
i tried by installing pymysql, i updated setup tools, in command prompt also it's displaying the same error.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql client
  Building wheel for mysql client (setup.  p y) ... error
  ERROR: Command error e d out with exit status 1:
   c

  building 'MySQL db._mys q l' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": ht t p s://visual studio. microsoft. com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------  
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysql client
  Running setup.p y clean for mysql client
Failed to build mysql client
Installing collected packages: mysql client
    Running setup.p y install for mysql client ... error
    ERROR: Command err o red out with exit status 1:
     command: '
```

i tried in many ways but didn't work.

```
k e, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NA ND A N\App Data\Local\Temp\pip-record-v t l g_81 u\install-record. t x t' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\n a n d an\n ex t p y t h on\pro j e c t 3\include\site\python 3.7\mysql client'
         cw d: C:\Users\NAN DA N\A p p D at a\Local\Temp\pip-install-f g 2 25 i w m\my s q l client\
    Complete output (24 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_p y
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7

    building 'MySQL  db._m m y s q l' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": ht t p s:/ / v is u a l stud i o. microsoft . com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command er r ore d out with exit status 1: 'e:\n an d a n\next p y t hon\pro j e c t 3\scripts\python.  e x e' -u -c 'import s y s, s e t up to o l  s, to k e n i z e; s y s. a r g v[0] = '"'"'.enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need it compiled from source, the easiest solution to this usually ends up being to install the binary directly:

```
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```

Hope that helps!